# jQuery .val() function cleans up '\r\n' from textarea - why?

Tags: jquery

I'm using `$("#text").val()` to get text from textarea field and send through ajax, but linebreaks (I mean `\r\n` in textarea) disappeares at all... Why could it be and how to prevent it?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try .prop('value'), im not sure if it would work the same as .val(), but that is kind of dumb to strip that out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Taken from [the documentation for `val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

> Note: At present, using .val() on textarea elements strips carriage
>   return characters from the browser-reported value. When this value is
>   sent to the server via XHR however, carriage returns are preserved (or
>   added by browsers which do not include them in the raw value). A
>   workaround for this issue can be achieved using a valHook as follows:
>
> ```
> $.valHooks.textarea = {
>   get: function( elem ) {
>       return elem.value.replace( /\r?\n/g, "\r\n" );
>   } };
> ```

Adding the above snippet to your javascript will override the default behaviour of `val()` for textareas and will preserve whitespace.

[See here for jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PpKan/)

Comment: how to use it on practice? first define valHooks and than use `val()` or what?

Comment: @VitaliPonomar jsFiddle to see usage.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vitali_Ponomar/PpKan/2/ what's wrong here? (look in firebug or chrome analog in Network->XHR->Headers: in `a` parametr '\r\n' removes)

Comment: but it helped when I replaced `.replace( /\r?\n/g, "<br>" )`! anyway I had later replace `\r\n` with `<br>`. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @VitaliPonomar You need to Uri encode the value in the query string - see http://jsfiddle.net/PpKan/3/ for update.

Comment: @RichO'Kelly thanks for this answer. Any reason why alert would work and printing to a div or span wouldn't? http://jsfiddle.net/cbc8n3qu/